# EC2 metrics-month calculation explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudwatch

I know if I need detailed monitoring per EC2 there is a cost involved. So even after making sure Detailed monitoring is turned off, I am getting billed for around 120+ metrics used. ( AWS-CloudWatch Charges 64.20)

No custom metrics are added anywhere so what is making the metrics tick?

Can anyone please explain how the EC2 per-metric month billing works?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Auto Scaling? If so, it might be activating detailed monitoring, which is $3.50 per instance per month.

Comment: `$0.50` per metric month is for AWS Custom Metrics. How did you check that you do not have custom metrics?

Comment: This is my billing page. I checked in the metrics section there are no custom metrics used by anyone anywhere.